# Unable to display the GUI and versions of XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using XCode 4.3 and I am creating a tab bar application following an example in my book (likely used for XCode version < 4.3) but when I add a new tab and turn on check-mark to generate XIB file while adding a new file of Cocoa Touch, the GUI doesn't appear but display instead its generated XML file content. Do you know how to fix this ?

I find each time there is a new version of XCode, the Gui and defined functions seem to change a lot, doesn't this annoy for low programmers like me ? (By *low*, I mean newbies and those who can't keep up with such rapid changes). Thank you.

You can view my shot here
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/appleimg.png/

Comment: I've never seen that, so I don't believe it's an intentional feature of Xcode.  Post the screenshots of your actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the .xib file and choose Open as...

There will be a list of options. Currently you are using "Source Code", which displays as XML. Use Interface Builder - iOS instead.

This will be remembered between sessions. I don't know how it got set to this in the first place.

Alternatively, you may be in the Version editor instead of the Standard editor - this will show xibs as XML in order to correctly display changes.